# How to implement Softmax output for Neural Network in Accord.net?

Tags: c#, neural-network, accord.net, softmax

In Accord Framework there are couple of activation functions such as Gaussian, Bernoulli, Sigmoid and so forth. Since those functions are for individual neurons and, frankly, I don't know how to implement softmax because I couldn't figure out how to access other neurons in the same visible layer (because the output of the neuron will be calculated using output of other neurons, as well.).

So, how can we implement a neural network with the output as a probability distribution?

Comment: I would advise waiting before using the .Neuro namespace of Accord.NET before the project finishes TensorFlow integration.